# No Database Selected - PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to my database and when I run the code, I get an error. Can anybody tell me what is wrong also any errors in my PHP code? Thanks.

```
Error: No database selected
```

**PHP Code:**

```
include('.conf.php');
$prof = $_GET['profile'];
$prof = addslashes(htmlentities($prof));
$query = "SELECT * FROM aTable where id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($prof)."'";
$info_array = mysql_query($query, $con) or die (mysql_error()).;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $info_array )) 
{
    echo $row['num1'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $row['num2'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $row['num3'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $row['num4'];
};

mysql_close($con);
```

**.conf.php** file:

```
<?php
    $conf['db_hostname'] = "xxx";
    $conf['db_username'] = "xxx";
    $conf['db_password'] = "xxx";
    $conf['db_name'] = "xxx";
    $conf['db_type'] = "mysql";

    $con = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx') or die (mysql_error());
    $db  = mysql_select_db("aTable", $con);
?>
```

Comment: mysql_select_db("aTable", $con);
is aTable the name of your DB? sounds like a table name for some reason:)

Comment: Try putting an `or die (mysql_error());` on the `select_db()` line to see if it outputs any errors.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of mysql_select_db() (i.e. $db) whether it is FALSE?

Comment: @JamWaffles the error is `Access denied for user 'xxx'@'%' to database 'aTable'`

Comment: @JosephTorraca There you have it then - you need to grant access to user `xxx` on database `aTable`

Comment: How do I do that? Im pretty new to PHP and MYsql

Comment: @JosephTorraca Unless `aTable` really isn't the name of your database. It is the name of your table...

Comment: Its the name of my table in a database

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless you have the password incorrect and need to fix it, run a `GRANT` statement to grant access to your database user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON aTable.* TO xxx@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_xxx';
```

The above grants all privileges. It's often better to restrict to only what's needed. For example, if you only intend to SELECT, but not modify data,

```
GRANT SELECT ON aTable.* TO xxx@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_xxx';
```

#### Update

Since you have identified the database name as `dedbmysql`, change your `mysql_select_db()` call to:

```
$db = mysql_select_db("dedbmysql", $con);
```

Following this, the `GRANT` statements above are probably unnecessary, as your host may have already worked out the correct database permissions.

Comment: I just tried to run it on PHPmyAdmin and it gives me this error: `#1044 - Access denied for user 'xxx'@'%' to database 'xxx' `

Comment: @JosephTorraca What is the actual name of your database? `aTable` is clearly the name of the table, but the database must have a different name.

Comment: @JosephTorraca See change above then. You need to fix `mysql_select_db()`

Answer (score 22):

I had that problem and solved it with prefixing the table name with the database name, so

```
 select * from database.table
```