# web app can't interact with sql database- possibly permissions but all looks fine?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a php web app I'm trying to run locally on an xampp localhost setup. The web app came with a config file that gave space to enter the database name, the username and password. I entered all of these (quadtripple checked all these match up to the SQL details entered into PhpMyAdmin). I had to create a database and import tables from the web app file when i first loaded it. The problem is that when I load the web app up, it doesn't interact with said database. I don't get any errors, and on the site it says for example that a new user has been created, but when I go to the database i can see that there is no new entry. existing users in the database also can not be entered in as it says incorrect user/pass (i.e. it can not read the database either). I'm pretty sure that the web app isn't broken, and the fault is mine somehow. any suggestions about whats going wrong, guys?

Comment: Which web app are you trying to install?

Comment: its a custom web-app that i'm having developed, has user log ins, and then just pulls information to and from a database depending on calls from the site. I don't have much php experience but i'm not entirely new to coding, having done visual basic & ms access back in the day.

Comment: Since it is a custom built app, there are chances that there is errors in the database interaction part of your application. Can you share the relavant parts of the database connection part of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app says incorrect username /pass that means it is interacting with the database or else you'd have got errors.
and if the app is interacting with database and you are still getting wrong username password notification then checkout your login processing script as there might be an encryption or something.??
Please make your question little clear if I'm wrong.

Comment: A screenshot of the problem might be helpfull, if it is possible.

Comment: Well, the issue is that *this* part of the site was working previously when i was using a differnt package called 'easyphp' instead of xampp. I switched to xampp because I was getting an  'object not found' error on some pages which were apparently related specifically to easyphp- but it did let me log in and create a new user. So to sum, easyphp= error messages on some pages but interacts with database, xampp = no error messages at all, but no interaction that i can see

Comment: Your question is still not clear, you have a login page in your web app, right? and when you try to login it says incorrect usernam/password?
And when you try to create a user, check the php script which is having query to insert user in database.

Comment: ill do a screen recording of interaction and post it up, it will take a little time though.

Comment: yeah it says incorrect user/pass, even though i know them to be correct (I can see them in the database). also, when i click 'create a new user' and fill in the details, it says successful but i can not see any new entry into the database and the logins i just created do not work. I'm about to do a screen recording now.

Comment: can i see your connection code, you are using for database connection

Comment: yes your new login doesn't work because they are not added to database.
And that must be problem with either your database connection or your query.

Share your connection script !!

Most probably it's your connection as you can't login with a correct password even.

Comment: sure, here's the accounts.php file http://www.scribd.com/doc/116019226/accounts-php?secret_password=1855u4a7jt8yothkhm4d

Comment: here is the config file http://www.scribd.com/doc/116019607/config?secret_password=132fgo95lerlvulg64za

Comment: and here is the includes http://www.scribd.com/doc/116019705/includes?secret_password=1un0h61h05hc2v4sifo1

Comment: when you are executing the insert query you are not checking it whether the query executed or not and you are just redirecting the user that's why you get "user created" or sign in message.
add $mysqli->error in your accounts file to check for mysql error and 
add a if on query i.e if($result=$mysqli-query("")){redirect}
 else 
printf($mysqli->error)

Comment: so the query does not execute, and it just does not handle the error properly? then why does it not execute? :S

Comment: you have to check it through $mysqli->error, only that could tell you exact problem that could be your wrong query, database structure, missing table or connection problem.
I've tried adding the suggested code, here it is 
http://pastebin.com/ri8yXCgd

Comment: ok, i've run that and now am getting this error:
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function Page() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\build3\accounts.php on line 14"

Comment: ya it is there in your code you are using a function twice in your account file, it is echoPage and i think it is misspelle as echo Page, so just remove the space from both the occurances and make sure it is echoPage and NOT echo Page

Comment: EDIT: sorry, the error is now gone :) will try create account and see if original problem is fixed...

Comment: now when i try to create an account, it doesnt say successful, it says "No database selected" :/

Comment: in you includes file $navList, $navPath ,
Shouldn't be they like $navList=array("","","") similarly $navPath=array("","","")

Comment: no database selected, have you created the database 'build' ??, because i tried the same configuration and have no database error instead a error in your redirection code at the last loop.

Comment: so currently in my includes i have..     $navList = ["Home", "Dashboard", "Profile", "Sign in"];
 $navPath = ["index.php", "dashboard.php", "profile.php", "accounts.php"];         should i just add 'array' after navList= and navPath= ?   *edit*: and change the [ to (?

Comment: yeah i definitely created the database 'build', and imported the relevant tables

Comment: make it $navList=array("Home", "Dashboard", "Profile", "Sign in");
$navPath = array("index.php", "dashboard.php", "profile.php", "accounts.php");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513484/no-database-selected-php-mysql

check your user permissions because I ran you code through my root user maybe that's why it is working for me

Comment: done, still has a error saying no database selected when creating an account, and just says password or username incorrect when logging in

Comment: Any improvements?
You can use your root user if you are working locally else if you are working on some remote site and you have a cpanel just change the user permissions.

Comment: I forgot to thank you for your help back in December- Thanks, I got it working with your help!

Comment: Oh that's good, I thought I couldn't help you solving the problem.

Happy to Help... Cheers...!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the app itself does *not* mention any problems it is clear that it does store new entries somewhere. Most likely the app is able to use different database engines, this is a very typical scheme these days. Probably it writes into a local file bases sqlite database whilst you entered credentials for a database inside a mysql server you also monitor using phpMyAdmin.

Check the file where you entered the credentials for traces of different locations the app is capable of storing. Maybe post the file here.

Comment: I also did a test by dropping the database completely and seeing what happened, there is still no error and no change to what the app does. when creating a new username it says successful but then the new user & pass combo can't be used. T

Comment: Well yeah, that is why I suggested that most likely the app uses another database engine, _not_ your mysql server.